# Swift Ternary, return tested value

Tags: swift, ternary

In my code, I check if a system function is equal to zero or not, if yes I return an other value, if not, I return the tested value.

```
    (class.verylongfunc(arg, arg) == 0) ? othervar : class.verylongfunc(arg, arg)
```

Here is a better and cleaner way to do that ? I don't want to call the function two times...
I know I can do

```
  let tmp = class.verylongfunc(arg, arg)
  (tmp == 0) ? othervar : tmp
```

But it take two lines...

Comment: It's not a real problem by the way, it's just I want my code cleaner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you control `verylongfunc`?  If so, is 0 a special case meaning some kind of failure or no possible return?  If so, have it return nil, then you can do

```
class.verylongfunc(arg, arg) ?? othervar
```

If not, make your own operator:

```
infix operator ??? {}
func ???(num: Int32, defNum: Int32) -> Int32 {
    if num == 0 {
        return defNum
    }
    return num
}
```

Comment: The func is 
"func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int"
Your answer is pretty good in some way, but except if I do an other func who call this one, I can't do that

Comment: @1L30 In this case, you shouldn't have to *ask* the collection view how many items are in a section… you should just be able to look at your data model and *know*

Comment: I actually asking my super class, I'm in a child class

Comment: I added more -- you can make your own operator for this case.

Comment: From a style perspective, I wouldn't make a custom operator for this.

Comment: I love this way to solve that, especially because it's pretty generic

Comment: Also you may want `@autoclosure` for `defNum` in case it is used like `verylongfn(arg) ??? anotherlongfn(arg2)`

Comment: @AaronBrager: I agree. If it became part of a standard or in Runes, fine. But, no one will understand it just by looking at it.

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way possible?

```
let value = someLongFunc()

if value == 0 {
   return otherValue 
} else {
   return value
}
```

I guarantee you that everyone that reads it will understand it with no second thoughts. You could make some operators or helper functions, but what is a "clean way" really? Fewer lines of code? I strongly disagree with that. Readability is much more important in "clean code" than hacking one liners and only terrible people abuse ternary operators.

Comment: The else is not mandatory since the first return will lead to an exit condition. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Lou Franco's answer, if you don't control `verylongfunc`, you can wrap the system function in a function that *does* return an optional:

```
func value() -> Int? {
    let value = Class.verylongfunc()
    return value == 0 ? nil : value
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
let otherVar = 123
let x = value() ?? otherVar
```

Comment: it is not much cleaner than just using the ternary

Comment: You right, I can do that, but don't you just move the problem in an other func with     return value == 0 ? nil : value
?

Comment: I agree. It's only valuable if you would be calling `value()` from many places, otherwise the abstraction is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Another one line solution.

```
let result = { $0 == 0 ? othervar : $0 }(class.verylongfunc(arg, arg))
```

Answer (score 0):

FruitAddict has the best idea for real-life code (people can understand who come after you)
& Bryan Chen has the cleverest solution if this question is interpreted by Spok with the specific requirement it be 1-line style;
HOWEVER, Chen's solution isn't really 1 line since you'd have to write a second line => 'return result' to meet the specific semantics ("RETURN otherval..." as if your line of code is inside a function) of the question.  To fix Chen's solution you can actually use the Ternary Operator with RETURN:

return { $0 == 0 ? othervar : $0 }(class.verylongfunc(arg, arg))

color commentary:  "$0" means "an object" or expression similar to 'self' and in this case is represented by what's inside the parentheses. The curly-brackets "{}" for Chen act as a "computed property" but in this case act as the return value, and inside the curly brackets the ternary operator is used.

This would be the MOST anal answer to this question.

But it ALSO answers another cool question: **How do you use the Ternary Operator with RETURN?**

(FYI: I upvoted Bryan Chen)